# how to open pdf file with default apps and auto navigate to specific page

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

so i found a way to open pdf file using [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file/example) but now i want to open with specific page.. for example there is 10 page and i want to navigate to page 5 as initial page when it is done opening from default app.. is there a way to achieve that?? i want to avoid open pdf in app using other plugin.. the thing is i have like 360 page pdf and i want user to be able to open to specific page when he pressed a button...

Answer (score 0):

`open_file` plugin can't do that.
[here](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/crazecoder/openfile/OpenFilePlugin.java) for android source code and [here](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/blob/master/ios/Classes/OpenFilePlugin.m) for iOS source code.
You may change to another plugin such as [syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer) or any one can do this.